# upload .pcm file using okhttp

Tags: audio, okhttp, nuance

I am trying to convert speech to text using Nuance so i am trying to send this request

```
curl "https://dictation.nuancemobility.net:443/NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation?appId=[INSERT YOUR APP ID]&appKey=[INSERT YOUR 128-BYTE STRING APP KEY]&id=C4461956B60B" -H "Content-Type: audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000" -H "Accept-Language: ENUS" -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Accept-Topic: Dictation" -k --data-binary @audio_16k16bit.pcm
```

need to upload audio file (.pcm) format.

I am using okhttp3 library following is the builder

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file", "audio_16k16bit.pcm", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, "audio_16k16bit"))
                .build();


    httpBuider.addQueryParameter("appId", "NMDPTRIAL_XXXXXXX_XXX_com20161122071457").addQueryParameter("appKey", "fadaed7b801e10d84272c0a75317d8cee13ab86ae902ab322cd6e1219fcbe79aa5d41526f225fe3497bfdbead6b4b9b7ee7122d773cd0a9fa3ebc042b7a7dc5c");
    Request request = new Request.Builder().addHeader("Content-Type","audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000").addHeader("Accept-Language","eng-GBR").addHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked").addHeader("Accept","application/xml").addHeader("Accept-Topic","Dictation").post(requestBody).url(httpBuider.build()).build();
```

I am getting following log

> ### HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation. Reason:
>
> ```
>     Server Error
> ```

Missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same just now using Jersey. Problem for me was, that Jersey was overwriting the content type header (I tried with `Application_Octet_Stream`).

Here is the request with which I finally got it to work:

```
Response myResponse = target.
request().
accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).
header("Accept-Language","DEDE").
header("Accept-Topic", "Dictation").
header("Transfer-Encoding","chunked").
post(Entity.entity(speechStream, "audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000"));
```

I suggest using something like fiddler to find out what is really posted and comparing that to the curl post. This is how I finally found out what was wrong with my request.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the header `"Transfer-Encoding","chunked"`. My error was fixed by removing it.